# 'property: 0.5px' or 'property: .5px' in CSS?

Tags: css, properties, zero

I've seen this notation used a lot, and I was wondering, is there is any notable difference between these two notations?

```
element#id
{
  property: 0.5px;
}
```

and

```
element#id
{
  property: .5px;
}
```

I use `property: .5px;` all the time, as I find it cleaner looking.

Does anyone know which one is better or correct? I didn't find this situation in the w3 specification.

Thanks!

Comment: `0.5=.5` in mathematics and in CSS and in programming mostly

Comment: There's no difference, it renders the same way. However, some people use the 0 at the front because occasionally the period is missed, being so small. Many hours of coding and all that ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are correct. This is stated in [section 4.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#numbers). Specifically:

> A <number> can either be an <integer>, or it can be zero or more digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more digits.

The only difference between them is a `0` character; whether you choose to include the leading `0` is entirely up to individual preference.